# Reverted to VSC 1.31.1 for macOS but Outline not working

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, outline-view

I reverted to VSC 1.31.1 for macOS because of several changes that for me made it worse then v. 1.31. I got everything to write and build a project. The only thing not working is the Outline. No matter what file is open the Outline panel says "There are no editors open that can provide outline information." The files are Haxe code files.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't try to use such an old version, as manual rollback might not get the extensions to a stable state. Why cannot you use 1.44.x?

Comment: Since 1.31 the few UI changes that affect me I hate. The outline is more intrusive than helpful. Any edit will expand the whole outline showing variables, etc. that are only local to functions I'm not editing. What use is that? Pasting causes indenting of not only the lines I paste, but lines above and/or below that I don't want. There should be settings to restore old behaviors. I've complained about these before but nothing is explained let alone changed.